# oauth2client Credentials refresh_token becomes null

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-python-client, oauth2client

### Backgound

1. I got access_token to Google API using the [google-api-python-client django_sample](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/#hg%2Fsamples%2Fdjango_sample%2Fplus).
2. To have offline access, I've added `FLOW.params['access_type'] = 'offline'`.
3. Stored `credentials_json = credentials.to_json()`. It contains a `refresh_token`.
4. Restored the credentials `Credentials.new_from_json(credentials_json)`.
5. Used this credentials to gain access by `credentials.authorize(http)`.
6. Worked perfectly =)

### The problem

1. I did the the same every 5 minutes.
2. In each iteration I stored the credentials and printed it.
3. After 1 hour and 45 minutes, the "refresh_token" became null.
4. At this point the code stopped working =(

### My questions

1. Does `Credentials` class refresh it's token automatically?
2. If not, at what point of should I call `credentials.refresh(http)`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Your refresh token is used to get a new access token every time that the access token expires.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/authentication#access_token_expiration) google says that the access token is automatically refreshed using the refresh token when it expires.

In our application, we call `credentials.refresh(http)` when the token is near to expiry

`if (credentials.token_expiry - datetime.utcnow()) < timedelta(minutes=refresh_mins):
    credentials.refresh(httplib2.Http())`

`refresh_mins` has a default value of 15 in our code base. This is because the access token expires in 60 minutes. We refresh every 45 mins. More details about this can be found [here](http://www.slideshare.net/marcwan/06-o-auth-20-advanced)

Comment: What does it mean when Google says: "By default, our client libraries automatically refresh expired access tokens." ? the refresh method should be called manually, shouldn't it ?

Comment: No, I think it is called automatically for you by the library

Comment: And what about refresh tokens? can they be expired?